# How to add dropdowns to this custom flexbox navigation bar I have created?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, navigation

I have created a custom flexbox nav that works exactly the way I intended it to, except for one thing. I need to add dropdowns on a few of the navbar items and I have tried every resource I can. I know some of the formatting is a little strange, and that is just the way the Real Geeks platform makes one edit.

**CSS**

```
.bg-palette-navigationBackground-color {
  background-color: transparent;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

body {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.45em;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #FFF;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #404041;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 500;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.45em;
}

#logo img{
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 25%;
}


#main-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  padding-right: -10px;
}

.nav-icon {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
}

.nav-icon:before,
.nav-icon:after {
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-icon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.nav-icon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #404041;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  text-decoration: overline 3px #beaf87;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: overline 3px #beaf87;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul li {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 170px;
}

li>a:after {
  content: '';
}

li>a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}


/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

  nav {
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav ul{
    float:none;
  }
  .toggle+a,
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #404041;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }

  .toggle:hover {
  text-decoration: overline 3px #beaf87;
  }

  [id^=drop]:checked+ul {
    display: block;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }

  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 0 80px;
  }

  nav ul ul ul a {
    background-color: #404041;
  }

  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    background-color: #404041;
  }

  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  nav ul ul li:hover>ul,
  nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display: none;
  }

  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul ul ul li {
    position: static;

  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav><label id="main-toggle" class="toggle" for="drop"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label> <input id="drop" type="checkbox" />
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><!-- First Tier Drop Down --> <label class="toggle" for="drop-1">SELLER SERVICES</label> <a href="#">SELLER SERVICES</a> <input id="drop-1" type="checkbox" />
<ul>
<li><a href="#">SERVICES OVERVIEW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">INSTANT HOME VALUATION</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><!-- First Tier Drop Down --> <label class="toggle" for="drop-1">BUYER SERVICES</label> <a href="#">BUYER SERVICES</a> <input id="drop-1" type="checkbox" />
<ul>
<li><a href="#">SERVICES OVERVIEW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FINANCING</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">RELOCATION</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MILITARY SERVICES</a></li>
<li><!-- First Tier Drop Down --> <label class="toggle" for="drop-1">FIND AN AGENT</label> <a href="#">FIND AN AGENT</a> <input id="drop-1" type="checkbox" />
<ul>
<li><a href="#">BOILING SPRINGS OFFICE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SPARTANBURG OFFICE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GREENVILLE OFFICE</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><!-- First Tier Drop Down --> <label class="toggle" for="drop-1">ABOUT</label> <a href="#">ABOUT</a> <input id="drop-1" type="checkbox" />
<ul>
<li><a href="#">CENTURY 21 BLACKWELL</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CENTURY 21</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">AGENT PORTAL</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your code is quite messy and overcomplicated, it would be easier to redo it from scratch.

I'd suggest you take a look at this:

https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/

It might help you understand what you need to replicate to achieve the desired effect.

If you still want to edit your own code, you basically have to replicate the same ul > li structure even within your code, i.e.:

```
<li>
    <label class="toggle" for="drop-1">TEST DPDWN</label>
    <input id="drop-1" type="checkbox" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES OVERVIEW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">INSTANT HOME VALUATION</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It might be a bit tough because you really need to clean your code. Also try to avoid absolute positioning and float unless absolutely necessary (you should just forget about float entirely)